# Jquery Events on Bootstrap Tabs created dynamically doesn't work

Tags: jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm having some issue with DOM flow with jquery and bootstrap.

I need to create TABS (not single tab) dinamically with some events attached on tabs switching. On this example the TABS is created just "Live" appending the code after loading page. This works fine! http://www.bootply.com/63026  On click on tab the Alert is shown.

But... if I create the TABS later, for example calling it by a button click like here: http://www.bootply.com/63033 it not works any more. The tabs are created on click but switching the tabs i have no more the popup attached on event.

Can you help me to fix it?  THANKS!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a listener:

```
$('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
```

to add tabs.

You need to update this to

```
 $(document).on('click', '.add-contact', function(e) {
```

Also change

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    alert(e.target) // activated tab
    e.relatedTarget // previous tab
});
```

to

```
$(document).on('shown', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    alert(e.target) // activated tab
    e.relatedTarget // previous tab
});
```

Comment: typo $(document) not $('document')

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the http://www.bootply.com/63033  but it not works. I need to show the alert on tab click

Comment: Done but it dosent works. I have also add an alert in  $(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e){...}  but... same!

Comment: check the edit. you needed to have an active listener.

Comment: Right!!!  It seem to be the missing code! Let me try on my dev code... yes! Perfect!! I was missing it! Thanks a lot!